# Git un-apply stash?

Tags: git, git-stash, git-apply

I have debug code for couple situations. I store it in stashes. They touches many files. Sometimes in process of coding I need to do `debug stash apply`.

But after resolving situation there is no way to un-stash temporary "debug2" code back.
I should do revert files or in worst case scenario only debug lines of code in classes that I`ve touched previously by hand.

I know that it possible to do first code `commit`, then `debug stash apply` and `debug commit`. And then do third code `commit`. But it's uncomfortably if I'm not sure that all working changes should go to first code commit.

Is there a way to just un-apply same debug stash code on fly?

Also maybe you know better idea how to work with temporary debug code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one example: [Un-applying a Stash](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Stashing#Un-applying-a-Stash)

```
git stash show -p | git apply -R
```

Comment: Works, but does not delete untracked stash files after using `git stash --include-untracked`

Comment: Edited final variant:
`git config --global alias.unapply '!git stash show -p | git apply -R | git clean -df'`

After this:
`git stash apply` - to add temporary code.
`git unapply` - to remove

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to un-apply stash is :

```
git reset --hard
```

and after checking out to the branch you choose, run this in your Git Bash:

```
git clean -d -f
```